# I need an idea for "retractable" panel 

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Like a "start" button on windows ) or something like that, I want to make "retractable" to filtering properties and I'm interesting is there some WinForms solution for it.

C# or another CLI language - No matters. But solution must be free...

with "retractable" I mean alike http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Accordion/Accordion.aspx but a single panel.

Thank you.

Comment: @Javed Akram , updated question with example

Comment: Check [accordion question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303195/winforms-accordion) and [show/hide question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505117/show-hide-details-winform)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a free [DropDownPanel](http://www.codeproject.com/cs/miscctrl/DropDownPanel.asp) on CodeProject that might meet your needs.

I have used it successfully in the past though there are some bugs related to docking.

Comment: +1, this one should to the job. btw the link is to codeproject not codePlex :)

Answer (score 1):

Viblend has also a free control that might do the work. You can find it [here](http://www.viblend.com/products/net/windows-forms/controls/free-winforms-controls.aspx).

I'm not sure thought if you can set it to show only one panel at a time.